# Export from Figma to Flinto, Principle, After Effects

Tags: export, adobe-after-effects, principle-app, figma

I’m considering to switch from Sketch to Figma. 
But there is a serious blocker: I can’t export Figma designs to the apps I’m actively using for prototyping and animations – Flinto, Principle, After Effects. There are plugins for Sketch for export to these apps, but I can’t find any solutions for Figma. Please share if you know any solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Jon Gold from Airbnb is currently developing a solution for using figma objects directly in AfterEffects.
He will open source it soon, you can check out  his tweet: https://twitter.com/jongold/status/1024047298412666880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principle has now extended support to Figma. So now you can directly import files to Principle. Also i think Framer supports figma, just have to check.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a tool to export from Figma to After Effects (you export into a JSON file and import it into AE using the AEUX plugin). You can check the latest developments on https://figma.aeux.io/